# Subsetting character string and returning string

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I was wondering if there was a clean solution using data.table to the following problem possibly using other packages such as stringr.

Suppose I have the following data table

```
DT <- data.table(name = c("Carlos", "Henry", "John"), 
    ID = c("US115115, CH123232, AB155, US4445", "CH112, BB53", "US57677777"))
```

This looks like:

```
     name                                ID
1: Carlos US115115, CH123232, AB155, US4445
2:  Henry                       CH112, BB53
3:   John                        US57677777
```

What I want to do is create another column, ID2, say, that takes the column ID and extracts only the "US identities" and creates a new column so that the final data table should look like:

```
     name                                ID              ID2
1: Carlos US115115, CH123232, AB155, US4445 US115115, US4445
2:  Henry                       CH112, BB53               NA
3:   John                        US57677777       US57677777
```

and where each element is a string. I've been able to code a version where it takes the first "US identity" and discards the rest, but I haven't been able to find a solution that handles multiplicity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach:

```
DT[, ID2 := sapply(strsplit(ID, ","), 
    function(s) paste(s[grepl("\\s*US", s)], collapse=","))]
```

output:

```
     name                                ID              ID2
1: Carlos US115115, CH123232, AB155, US4445 US115115, US4445
2:  Henry                       CH112, BB53                 
3:   John                        US57677777       US57677777
```

Comment: You could avoid the `trimws` if you change your regex to `",\\s*"` , but this seems pretty good to me.

Comment: Also I think `sapply(strsplit(DT$ID, ","), function(s) toString(grep("^US", trimws(s), value = TRUE)))` would be a bit shorter ?

Comment: thanks, @latemail. have taken your comments into the solution

Comment: very nice, @RonakShah. You should post that as well, i find it useful as i learned that `toString` does `string <- paste(x, collapse = ", ")` as well

Answer (score 2):

Here are few suggestions inspired from @thelatemail and @chinsoon12

```
DT$ID1 <- sapply(strsplit(DT$ID, ",\\s*"), function(x) 
                            toString(grep("^US", x, value = TRUE)))
DT
#     name                                ID              ID1
#1: Carlos US115115, CH123232, AB155, US4445 US115115, US4445
#2:  Henry                       CH112, BB53                 
#3:   John                        US57677777       US57677777
```

Above we are filtering using `grep`, we can also use `startsWith` to do the same

```
sapply(strsplit(DT$ID, ",\\s*"), function(x) toString(x[startsWith(x, "US")]))
```

---

You can incorporate both the above options in `dplyr` chain however another option using `dplyr` and `tidyr` would be using `separate_rows` which might be an overkill for this particular question. We can use `str_subset` from `stringr` which is the same as `grep("^US", x, value = TRUE)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DT %>%
  separate_rows(ID) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(ID1 = toString(ID), 
            ID2 = toString(stringr::str_subset(ID, "^US")))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can either use `str_extract` to extract the words that start with "US"

```
library(stringr)
DT[, ID2 := sapply(str_extract_all(ID, "\\bUS\\S*"), toString)]
DT
#     name                                ID               ID2
#1: Carlos US115115, CH123232, AB155, US4445 US115115,, US4445
#2:  Henry                       CH112, BB53                  
#3:   John                        US57677777        US57677777
```

Or using `gsub`

```
DT[, ID2 := gsub("(\\bUS\\S*)(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", ID, perl = TRUE)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
DT %>%
    mutate(ID2 = str_extract_all(ID, "\\bUS\\S*") %>%
                   map(toString))
```

---

Or with `base R` using `gregexpr`

```
DT$ID2 <- sapply(regmatches(DT$ID, gregexpr("\\bUS\\S*", DT$ID)), toString)
```